# Thread safety and std::move

Tags: c++, lambda, thread-safety, move

---

**Preface:**
When I'm typing out new code, I declare my functions as *pass-by-reference-to-const* without thinking (out of habit), and sometimes have to go back and change it when I realize it's not what I meant to do.

I'm writing a worker-thread class that runs indefinitely, and is fed strings (from another thread) for processing. When I realized that I had declared the function as *pass-by-ref*, I went back to change it to *pass-by-value*, for thread-safety.

But, since I would like to squeeze out as much speed and efficiency as possible, I stopped myself to first explore the options. I wrote a little test routine - and discovered that I'm fuzzy on some key concepts.

---

**To the point:** I first wrote the test code below without the commented line:

```
// std::thread _thread(workthread, move(str)); // Thread safe (contents are moved)
```

So, ignore that line for now.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <atomic>

std::atomic<bool> done = false;

void workthread(const std::string &str)
{
    std::string &s = const_cast<std::string &>(str);
    s = "Work Thread"; // test to see if this changes the main thread's string
}

// This just watches for <enter> on the keyboard in order to quit the program.
void quitmonitor()
{
    std::getchar();
    done = true;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    std::thread _monitor(quitmonitor);
    std::string str("Main Thread");

    std::thread _thread([&]{workthread(std::move(str));}); // Not thread safe (address is copied)
//  std::thread _thread(workthread, move(str));            // Thread safe (contents are moved)

    const auto minlen(str.length());
    const auto maxlen(minlen ? minlen*2 : 15);
    bool going_up = true;

    while (!done) {

        if (going_up)
            str.push_back('+');
        else
            str.pop_back();

        if (str.length() == minlen)
            going_up = true;
        if (str.length() == maxlen)
            going_up = false;

        std::cout << str << "\n";
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));
    }

    _thread.join();
    _monitor.join();
}
```

All `main()` does is create a string *"Main Thread"*, and moves it to the thread function `void workthread(const std::string &)`. The thread function then changes the lvalue's data and returns. The main continues on to a loop which just prints its local string to console (with some additional eye-candy to make it easy to see things happening on the screen). Here's the output:

[image: function called with lambda]

So, it didn't work as I had expected. I had thought that the thread instantiation would "move" `str` to the thread function (emptying its data in the process), and the thread's assignment to the function's string argument would have no affect. But clearly it did, as demonstrated by the output.

This must have something to do with the fact that I constructed `_thread` with a lambda:
`std::thread _thread([&]{workthread(std::move(str));}); // Not thread safe (address is copied)`

So then I changed the instantiation to:
`std::thread _thread(workthread, move(str));  // Thread safe (contents are moved)`
and it worked as expected:
[image: function called as bind]

**Q1:** Why do the two instances, lambda vs bind<sub>(I guess?)</sub>, yield different results?

**Q2:** Am I actually buying myself anything by declaring this as *pass-by-reference*?

*I should note that the actual program is quite time critical, and is intended to run uninterrupted for years on a dedicated server. I'm trying to make the software as low-overhead as possible, to ensure that it can stay in sync (with an external clock), and not accumulate time errors.*

Comment: You probably almost always want to copy/move data between threads. It's got to be a pain to debug dangling references and the like across threads, and you'd have a lot of ownership problems to worry about. If you are concerned about copying being expensive, consider using `std::shared_ptr` or `std::unique_ptr`, but be aware that they [aren't thread-safe](https://youtu.be/lkgszkPnV8g?t=20m10s).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> std::thread _thread([&]{workthread(std::move(str));});
> ```

When `_thread` is created, it calls your lambda function, which calls `workthread(std::move(str))`. Note that `std::move` doesn't actually do anything; it's just a cast to rvalue reference. You never move from `str`, you just cast the reference to a `std::string&` in a roundabout way and assign to it.

This also means that you have a data race on `str` because you have unsynchronized access between the main thread and `_thread`.

---

This code moved from the string, though:

> ```
> std::thread _thread(workthread, move(str));
> ```

If you look at [`std::thread`'s constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread) (it's (3) on that list), you'll see that it "copies" the arguments to the function call; it calls roughly:

```
workthread(decay_copy(std::move(str)))
```

This `decay_copy` actually does move from the string, as it returns by value:

> ```
> template <class T>
> std::decay_t<T> decay_copy(T&& v) { return std::forward<T>(v); }
> ```

This is why you see `str` as being moved from. However, your program is actually relying on unspecified behavior, as – after moving from a `std::string` – the string is left in a "valid but unspecified state" (`std::string`'s [move constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) and [move assignment operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%3D)). You can't expect `str` to be an empty string after it's been moved from.

Comment: "This also means that you have a data race on str because you have unsynchronized access between the main thread and _thread" -- Yes, this is what I discovered, as so mark the line as "// Not thread safe..."

Comment: Great answer. It was a big help. If I extrapolate your answer to my Q2, (ignoring the lambda, and focusing only on constructor #3), it seems like this doesn't buy me anything. I'm still left with a full deep copy. Would you agree?

Comment: @BlairFonville Yes, you do get a value. It could be copied (if you passed in an lvalue), or it could be moved (if you passed in an rvalue). In the case you showed in the question, it would be moved, which is very cheap.

Comment: Oh I follow you. Excellent. Thanks!